# Transfer rates on wireless network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

First of all, sorry for my English

What are the transfer rates of files between a network and a wireless AP?

I have a home server connected to a wireless router via ethernet and i'm not able to get more than 5-6 MB/S

- 2.4 ghz - 20MHz ----> 3-4 MB/s
- 2.4 ghz - 40MHz ----> 5-7.5 MB/s

**Clients** are notebook not compatibile with 5ghz.I tried with

- RT5390R (Ralink RT5390R 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter)
- RTL8188CE (Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n)
- INTEL 5100 (This one i think is n-draft)

**Router:**

- thomson TWG870
- Linksys wrt160Nv3 with and without dd-wrt

**IPERF:**

client(wifi)--->client(wifi)

```
[156]  0.0-60.0 sec   117 MBytes  1.94 MBytes/sec
```

client(wifi)--->client(ethernet)

```
[156]  0.0-60.0 sec   231 MBytes  3.86 MBytes/sec
```

In addition, i can download from internet(via ethernet of course) at 10 MB/s but with theese speed i get from my router i can not take advantage of

Comment: What are the specifications of the laptop's WiFi card? If it's 802.11g, that's actually better than I would have expected.

Comment: @Znau: He's measuring true data transfer rates, which are usually measured in MB/s.

Comment: What OS are you running?  FYI: Speed declines with an increase in distance.

Comment: Try to switch wireless channels use channels 1, 6 or 11.
Try to configure router to n-mode only.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure you're running in 'n' mode from client to ap, then you might check the router settings to make sure things like in dd-wrt > wireless > advanced that you don't have the transmission fixed rate set low.

also check for tx errors on the status page, if you have a lot of them you might try adjusting your ack timing (try 0, if it doesn't help try about how many meters you are from the ap and add 30)
if you're still dropping packets you might potentially lower your beacon interval to 50ms and adjust fragmentation and rts tresholds a little as well (follow the instructions here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings#Fragmentation_Threshold )